# How to get the value from a nested dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

Given the following nested dictionary I get back from the RIPE NCC RESTful API when creating a Person Object:

```
dict = {
   'link': {
       'type': 'locator', 
       'href': 'http://rest-test.db.ripe.net/test/person?dry-run=True'
   }, 
   'objects': {
       'object': [{
           'type': 'person', 
           'link': {
                'type': 'locator', 
                'href': 'https://rest-test.db.ripe.net/test/person/MT5-TEST'
            }, 
            'source': {
                'id': 'test'
            }, 
            'primary-key': {
                'attribute': [{
                    'name': 'nic-hdl', 
                    'value': 'MT5-TEST'
                 }]}, 
                    'attributes': { 
                        'attribute': [
                            {'name': 'person', 'value': 'Person test'}, 
                            {'name': 'address', 'value': 'Wegstraat 1'}, 
                            {'name': 'phone', 'value': '+31612345678'}, 
                            {'name': 'e-mail', 'value': 'person@company.com'}, 
                            {'link': {
                                'type': 'locator', 
                                'href': 'https://rest-test.db.ripe.net/test/mntner/TEST-DBM-MNT'}, 'name': 'mnt-by', 'value': 'TEST-DBM-MNT', 'referenced-type': 'mntner'}, 
                            {'name': 'nic-hdl', 'value': 'PT5-TEST'}, 
                            {'name': 'created', 'value': '2023-05-04T13:20:57Z'}, 
                            {'name': 'last-modified', 'value': '2023-05-04T13:20:57Z'}, 
                            {'name': 'source', 'value': 'TEST'}
                        ]
                    }
                }
                ]
                }, 
               'errormessages': {
                   'errormessage': [{
                       'severity': 'Info', 
                       'text': 'Dry-run performed, no changes to the database have been made'}
                    ]
                }, 
                'terms-and-conditions': {
                    'type': 'locator', 
                    'href': 'http://www.ripe.net/db/support/db-terms-conditions.pdf'
          }
      }
```

To get, for example, the 'nic-hdl' value I would do something like this:

```
nic-hdl = ['objects']['object'][0]['primary-key']['attribute'][0]['value']
```

Which is completely fine. However, it doesn't seem to be very clean.

Same goes for the attributes, attribute part which contains a few more name, value pairs. What would be the best and cleanest way to get those values by its corresponding keys?

Comment: You have to be able to navigate the structure somehow. In this particular case, the data you want is associated with the key called 'value'. That key does not exist (in the data shown) in any other part of the dictionary. Therefore you could write code to work through the dictionary just searching for that key

Answer (score 1):

That's what functions are for.

First, I recommend that you change the variable name `dict` to something like `data`. That's because dict is a python reserved word.
So, this sample are considering the object is being called data

In order to make the code reading cleaner, you can try something like this:

```py
def get_object(name):
    obj = list(
        filter(
            lambda x:x['type'] == name,
            data['objects']['object']
        )
    )
    return obj[0]

def get_attribute_in_object(name, object):
    attribute = list(
        filter(
            lambda x:x['name'] == name,
            object['attributes']['attribute']
        )
    )
    return attribute[0]['value']

person = get_object('person')  # Get the object
person_name = get_attribute_in_object('person', person)  # Get the attribute from object
person_address = get_attribute_in_object('address', person)  # ...

print('name:',person_name)
print('address:',person_address)
```

This sample will return:

```
name: Person test
address: Wegstraat 1
```

Comment: This is much cleaner indeed. These functions would also work on other data structures I will be working with.

Answer (score 1):

For this particular case we can take a specialised approach.

The data structure only contains one dictionary that has a key called 'value'. Because of that, we can take a simple recursive approach to the problem whereby we only need to provide our function with the dictionary we're searching and the name of the key we're looking for.

Therefore:

```
data = {
   'link': {
       'type': 'locator', 
       'href': 'http://rest-test.db.ripe.net/test/person?dry-run=True'
   }, 
   'objects': {
       'object': [{
           'type': 'person', 
           'link': {
                'type': 'locator', 
                'href': 'https://rest-test.db.ripe.net/test/person/MT5-TEST'
            }, 
            'source': {
                'id': 'test'
            }, 
            'primary-key': {
                'attribute': [{
                    'name': 'nic-hdl', 
                    'value': 'MT5-TEST'
                 }]}, 
                    'attributes': { 
                        'attribute': [
                            {'name': 'person', 'value': 'Person test'}, 
                            {'name': 'address', 'value': 'Wegstraat 1'}, 
                            {'name': 'phone', 'value': '+31612345678'}, 
                            {'name': 'e-mail', 'value': 'person@company.com'}, 
                            {'link': {
                                'type': 'locator', 
                                'href': 'https://rest-test.db.ripe.net/test/mntner/TEST-DBM-MNT'}, 'name': 'mnt-by', 'value': 'TEST-DBM-MNT', 'referenced-type': 'mntner'}, 
                            {'name': 'nic-hdl', 'value': 'PT5-TEST'}, 
                            {'name': 'created', 'value': '2023-05-04T13:20:57Z'}, 
                            {'name': 'last-modified', 'value': '2023-05-04T13:20:57Z'}, 
                            {'name': 'source', 'value': 'TEST'}
                        ]
                    }
                }
                ]
                }, 
               'errormessages': {
                   'errormessage': [{
                       'severity': 'Info', 
                       'text': 'Dry-run performed, no changes to the database have been made'}
                    ]
                }, 
                'terms-and-conditions': {
                    'type': 'locator', 
                    'href': 'http://www.ripe.net/db/support/db-terms-conditions.pdf'
          }
      }

def findvalue(k, d):
    if isinstance(d, dict):
        if result := d.get(k):
            return result
        for v in d.values():
            if result := findvalue(k, v):
                return result
    else:
        if isinstance(d, list):
            for e in d:
                if result := findvalue(k, e):
                    return result

print(findvalue('value', data))
```

**Output:**

```
MT5-TEST
```

Comment: I am using your function a lot and it's been very useful thus far. However, there's one response object I get back from RIPE that somehow returns a multistring primary-key value:

Comment: @Beeelze Without seeing an example of the dictionary data I don't know how I can help

Comment: I'm sorry, it wasn't supposed to enter my comment just yet. Here is the multistring response that I get from requesting an inetnum object:
    'primary-key': {'attribute': [{'name': 'inetnum',
    'value': '144.178.67.0 '
    '- '
    '144.178.67.3'}]},

Comment: Your function returns None in this case.